# Is "to say" in Hamlet's "and by a sleep to say we end" an infinitive or an adverb?

Tags: infinitives, parts-of-speech, syntactic-analysis, early-modern-english, shakespeare

I was trying to identify the word classes of Hamlet's famous monologue "To be or not to be", and I'm really having trouble deciding what word class "to say" in "and by sleep **to say** we end the heartache, and the thousand natural shocks" belongs to.

Is it an infinitive construction, or is it an adverb?

Comment: Have you tried running the sentence in question through a parser to see what analysis it produces?

Comment: No I haven't. I'm not even sure what a parser is... >.<

Comment: I mean the natural language processing programs that you feed text to and which produce as output various types of syntactic analyses, including part-of-speech assignment and structural linkage, sometimes even in fancy graphics. There's a list or three of such resources on [our meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com) that you can toss this at, like the Stanford Parser tool.

Comment: You're conflating word class and word function. *To say* belongs to the lexical class of verbs, and in particular it's an infinitive form. Hamlet isn't speaking in textbook sentences. He mentions three things that he thinking about -- dying, sleeping, and saying something. Are these subjects, objects, modifiers? Hard to say, but those are all functions that the infinitive might take on.

Comment: Thank you both a lot! The parser also told me that it is a verb :) And since I used it for the first time - and was a bit suspicious of it -, I am glad deadreat confirmed the result! And thanks for pointing out the difference between function and class. I think I was working a bit to sloppy on the matter.